# jQuery Search entire div block for string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a block of code with various tags but all within a set of div tags.  I need to be able to search everything within the div block to replace a string with another.  Here is the block.

```
<div class="form-group field-thoughts-cmh0-thought required">
<label class="control-label" for="thoughts-cmh0-thought">cmh0.</label>
<input type="text" id="thoughts-cmh0-thought" class="form-control" name="Thoughts[cmh0][thought]">
<button type="button" class="entAdd"> Add Above </button> 
<button type="button" class="entDelete"> Delete </button>
<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is replace all of the 'cmh0' instances with another string.  I know I can do this one by one, but there is a very good chance the above block is going to change and change multiple times as time goes on.  Consequently, I'd like an elegant way to select and replace all of the 'cmh0' instances within the main div block.

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a [templating library](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)?

Comment: This is the first I've heard of a templating library and I'm not quite sure how I would use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a quick select and replace:

```
var container = $('div[class*="cmh0"]').parent();
container.html(container.html().replace(/cmh0/g, 'someotherclass'));
```

the `class*=` reads as, "select any element where the class contanis"`.

Then just replace the html and reapply it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42u4s006/)

Comment: Thanks!  This gave me exactly what I needed to solve the problem.  Really appreciate it!